# Show Chatter feed for Knowledge articles in the Napili template

Tags: knowledge, community, feeditem, articles, napili

I am trying to display feeds for articles in my Napili template using the standard record feed lightning component, but for knowledge articles, it never loads. It works properly for custom objects.

Image -
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled feed tracking? Go to Setup > Chatter > Feed Tracking then in the left panel scroll down to "Standard Article" then in the right panel check the "Enable Feed Tracking" You'll want to repeat this same process for all your custom article types.